# Is it possible to view the underlying tree of a database index?

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, postgresql, indexing

Nearly all database implementations offer the possibility of creating indexes, based on various data structures, that greatly speed up search speed.

Is it possible for any database - especially the most-used ones, such as MySQL, Postgres, MongoDB, etc - offer the ability to see how records are being stored? As in, to actually see the B-tree?

Comment: What kind of info were you hoping to discover?

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres you can use the [pageinspect extension.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html#idm46046811709280) It provides functions that allow you to inspect the contents of database pages at a low level.

Comment: It won't do what I expect @Micros is hoping for, some kind of tree visualisation or similar text-format equivalent. Though you could use its output to produce one with some work.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have any official tools to view internal index data structures, but developer Jeremy Cole created a set of tools to do that. He wrote about what he discovered in a series of blog posts:

https://blog.jcole.us/innodb/

He demonstrates his InnoDB inspection tools, which he made freely available on Github.